# JScrollBar + JTextPane with HTML not properly scrolling to maximum value

Tags: java, html, jtextpane, jscrollbar, htmleditorkit

I have the following problem in a project of mine, took me a while to figure out whats causing the problem, and I can reproduce it with this simple code which I attached.

I am dynamically adding content to a JTextPane with a HTMLEditorKit. I set autoscroll to off because I want to control it manually (when user scrolled up, to stop, and when an event is triggered to get activated again).

The problem now is, when I set the value of the JScrollBar to it's maximum value, it's a different one, just the moment, after having content inserted to the HTMLDocument. When I trigger the setValue again a second time manually, it scrolls to the correct maximum value.

It seems the JScrollBar is not aware about the correct maximumValue just right after adding to the HTMLDocument, and just a (delayed) time later.

Using

```
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

is not a solution, because it also doesn't work properly. It doesn't scroll to the maximum value too, leaving a view pixel below, which I don't want.

Here is the full code reproducing the issue. If you click on the right button (add & scroll), it inserts a DIV element to the body. The moment the last visible line is reached, it doesn't scroll correctly to the last maximum value, the last line is hidden. But when you just click on the left button manually to trigger a second scrollToEnd(), it scrolls correctly to the maximum value.

Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication26;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {

        initComponents();

        this.setSize(500, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.jTextPane1.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        this.jTextPane1.setContentType("text/html");

        this.jTextPane1.setText("<html><body><div id=\"GLOBALDIV\"></div></body></html>");

        this.jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        this.jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) this.jTextPane1.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);

        this.jScrollPane1.setAutoscrolls(false);
        this.jTextPane1.setAutoscrolls(false);
    }

    private void scrollToEnd() {

        this.jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(this.jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
        //this.jTextPane1.setCaretPosition(this.jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButton1.setText("Scroll to end");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.add(jButton1);

        jButton2.setText("Add & scroll");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.add(jButton2);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try {

            HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) this.jTextPane1.getDocument();
            HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit) this.jTextPane1.getEditorKit();

            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            String htmlCode = "<div style=\"background-color: #FFFF22; height: 12px; font-size: 12;\">"+new BigInteger(64, random).toString(64)+"</div>";

            //editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), htmlCode, 0, 0, null);
            Element element = doc.getElement("GLOBALDIV");

            if (element != null) {
                doc.insertBeforeEnd(element, htmlCode);
            }

            this.scrollToEnd();
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        this.scrollToEnd();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This code replacement works though, but leaves a small gap, also not properly scrolling to the maximum value:

```
this.jTextPane1.setCaretPosition(0);
this.jTextPane1.setCaretPosition(this.jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert the div into the document, the document model is being updated immediately. However, the `JTextPane` only receives a notification that it is invalid and needs to be laid out. This notification creates an event on the EDT which is only processed after the current event (triggered by the button clicked) has finished.

Thus, at the moment when you invoke `scrollToEnd()`, the revalidation of the `JTextPane` is still pending, and the height of the text pane is still too small.

In order to get the sequence of events right, you need to schedule the invokation of scrollToEnd() in the EDT, by using invokeLater:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         scrollToEnd();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to solve the issue! Is this the correct way to do something like this? What if I add lots of content dynamically to the pane, like a few lines per second. Wouldnt that "blow" the whole thing up, creating a new Runnable for every scrollToEnd()?

Comment: Whether this is correct depends on the exact use case. It is correct in the sense that the sequence of updating the model, then the view, is working properly. Since it detaches the model update from the view update, there might be rare use cases where this does not work correctly, e.g. when several conflicting updates to the model are not updating the GUI in the right order. However, this is very unlikely, as the EDT events which execute the runnable are sorted into the event queue in the order in which they are generated.

Comment: As for a higher load such as several lines per second, this should stil be ok. Instantiating the Runnable is not expensive, as it does _not_ create a new Thread. the `run()` method of the Runnables is called on the EDT thread, thus no new thread is created. You end up with a new object for each `invokeLater`, but that's acceptable (every Swing event has the same problem). 

If possible, it would of course be helpful to aggregate several model updates into a single `scrollToEnd()` update, but that depends on the logic which creates the document changes.

Comment: I think I was celebrating a bit too early. The problem still happens, but now very rarely, in my project, and I have no idea why. It has something to do with when there are images in the line added to the HTMLDocument, maybe the invokelater happens too fast and comes too late, can that happen? Would something like this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoScrollingEventswithaChangeListener.htm maybe make more sense or would it be a worse idea?

Comment: Adding a listener to the vertical scroll model, looking if the maxValue was changed (getting bigger), if bigger, calling a public function in the gui to scroll to new max?